Scattered C*-algebras
A $C^*$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ is called scattered if $\mathcal{A}^{**}$ is atomic, i.e. a direct sum of type I factors.
Obviously, $\mathcal{K}(H)$ is scattered. Other examples?
Observe also that scattered $C^*$-algebras are nuclear.( so an interesting category).

$B(H)$ is not an example. (Assuming you meant $H$ to be $\ell^2$.) By a result of Sakai, the Calkin algebra, and therefore $B(H)$, has type III representations, so $B(H)^{\ast\ast}$ has type III summands. (See also this paper of Anderson and Bunce, which shows the Calkin algebra also has type II$_\infty$ representations.) Moreover, note that $B(H)$ is not even nuclear.

$C^\ast$-algebras whose double duals are type I vNa’s are known as type I $C^\ast$-algebras, which are quite well-studied. You’re asking for something even stronger. I’m not well-versed in type I $C^\ast$-algebras, so I wouldn’t know how to prove it, but I wouldn’t be surprised if the only examples are like $c_0$-direct sums of matrix algebras and $K(H)$.

The paper Noncommutative Cantor-Bendixson derivatives and scattered C∗-algebras by
Ghasemi and Koszmider has a lot of information about scattered $C^*$-algebras.

@DavidGao Just to elaborate on Nik's comment: the intuition in your answer is understandable but incorrect/incomplete, even in the separable case. If $X$ is any compact scattered space ( https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Scattered_space ) then $C(X)^\ast\cong M(X)=\ell^1(X)$ (Rudin, PAMS 1957, https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-1957-0085475-7 ) and so $C(X)^{**}=\ell^\infty(X)$ is an atomic abelian vN algebra

@YemonChoi That makes sense. I suppose any countable compact space is already an example.

As a complement to what's written in the comments, there are several characterizations of scattered $C^*$-algebras in the literature, some of which are below.
Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra, then TFAE.

$A$ is scattered ($A^{**}$ is atomic)
$A^*$ has Radon Nikodym property. [Taylor1983 ,Theorem 3.5]
$A$ contains no subspace isomorphic to $\ell^1$.
$A$ contains no subspace isomorphic to $C([0,1])$.
The spectrum of every self-adjoint $x\in A$ is countable. [Huruya1978]
The left multiplication operators $L_a:A\to A$ are weakly precompact for all $a\in A$. [LauÜlger1993, Lemma 6.2]

As example; a $C^*$-algebra $A$ is said to be compact in old articles if the maps $x\to axa$ are compact for each $a\in A$. TFAE

$A$ is compact,
The left multiplication operators $L_a:A\to A$ are weakly compact for all $a\in A$, [Ylinen1975]
The right multiplication operators $R_a:A\to A$ are weakly compact for all $a\in A$, [Ylinen1975]
$A$ is an ideal of $A^{**}$,
$A$ is isomorphic to a $c_0$-sum $(\bigoplus_i K(H_i))_{c_0}$  [Kaplansky1951].

By above, every compact $C^*$-algebra is scattered.
As another example, let $G$ be a LCG. Then, the group $C^*$-algebra $C^*(G)$ is scattered iff every unitary representation of $G$ is atomic. [Taylor1983, Theorem 4.2]

Dear @Onur Oktay, the link is not available. Thank you for your answer.

@E.Papapetros The link should be working after the edit. I added a few more links.
